# SSH command exiting instantly instead of staying alive as python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess

I am try to use Python to set up a reverse SSH tunnel. Some software that starts with the system is going to manage it and kill it or start it based on commands it receives.

I have written a class to manage the reverse tunnel as follows:

```
# imports omitted for brevity
class SshProcess():
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = None

    def start(self, port):
        if self.process is not None:
            return None

        command = [
            # 'sudo',
            'ssh',
            '-R {port}:127.0.0.1:22'.format(port=port),
            '{username}@{host}'.format(username=config.USERNAME, host=config.HOST),
            '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
        ]

        def threaded_popen():
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(
                (' '.join(command)), # command, # shlex.split(command),
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                shell=True
            )

            self.process.wait()

            logger.info('Reverse SSH to {username}@{host} has exited'.format(username=config.USERNAME, host=config.HOST))

        logger.debug('command raw: {command}'.format(command=command))
        logger.debug('command joined: {command}'.format(command=(' '.join(command))))

        self.thread = Thread(target=threaded_popen)

        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.process is not None:
            try:
                self.process.communicate(input="exit\n")
                self.process.terminate()
            except (ValueError, OSError) as e:
                logger.warning('Closing reverse SSH raised {error}'.format(error=e.__class__.__name__))
                logger.warning(e)

        self.process = None

        if self.thread is not None:
            self.thread.join()
```

Now whenever I call start I receive the following log statements:

```
2017-06-28 14:32:46,343 - module - DEBUG - command raw: ['ssh', '-R 4000:127.0.0.1:22', 'tich@192.168.0.88', '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no']
2017-06-28 14:32:46,344 - module - DEBUG - command joined: ssh -R 4000:127.0.0.1:22 tich@192.168.0.88 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
2017-06-28 14:32:46,797 - module - INFO - Reverse SSH to tich@192.168.0.88 has exited
```

The issue is the ssh tunnel exits nearly instantly after starting. performing a simple `pidof ssh` in Linux gives no output as if the process does not even exist.

I have also tried using `communicate()` after starting the process and you can see it establishes the connection and receives output. However shortly after the function exits, the subprocess exits as well.

I have set up RSA keypairs for both the root and the regular user. Copying and pasting the command into a terminal does not produce the instant exit bug.

The purpose is setting up a reverse SSH session so a remote user can log in. But I currently have not found an existing packaged solution that offers this functionality.

Comment: use paramiko: http://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: Considered paramiko, looking at the docs it doesn't seem to provide the reverseoption anywhere. Meaning the target server can't ssh back into the source server.

Answer (score 0):

You done some weird ssh connection.My advice is to use paramiko a great ssh package.
on the other hand, you are sub-processioning only for a linux commamd so if u like it like that use:
install sshpass (yum install or apt-get)
sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname

and change this setting instead of the flag u sent:
change ssh_config
vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
change the below key from "ask" to "no"

StrictHostKeyChecking no

Comment: The command is weird because it sets up a reverse tunnel, on the other end you can use `ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 19999`. This is the main functionality, The SSH command works. But no library offers the options I use. The problem is, the SSH command won't stay alive, it is killed before anything useful can be done at the other end.